# Shorten nested if with else

Tags: c#, if-statement

Homework question. I've build an app that lets you calculate the ammount of discount.

3 radiobuttons.

```
rb_korting5  = 5% discount
rb_korting10 = 10% discount
rb_korting15 = 15% discount
```

and if your 65 or older you get an additonal +10 discount.

I need to shorten the follow code with else if. I've tried it but it keeps messing up the calculations.

```
public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime todate = DateTime.Today;
    int CurrentYear = todate.Year;
    int price = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Price.Text);
    int ammount = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Ammount.Text);
    double result = Convert.ToDouble(price * ammount);
    int dob = Convert.ToInt32(tb_dob.Text);
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear - dob);

    if ((rbkorting5.IsChecked == true) && ( age >= 65))         
    {
        result = result * 0.05 + 10;
    }

    if ((rbkorting5.IsChecked == true) && (age < 65))
    {
        result = result * 0.05;
    }


    if ((rbkorting10.IsChecked == true) && (age >= 65))
    {
        result = result * 0.10 + 10;
    }

    if ((rbkorting15.IsChecked == true) && (age >= 65))
    {
        result = result * 0.15 + 10;
    }


    if ((rbkorting10.IsChecked == true) && (age < 65))
    {
        result = result * 0.10;
    }

    if ((rbkorting15.IsChecked == true) && (age < 65))
    {
        result = result * 0.15;
    }

    lb_result.Content = result;
}
```

Comment: There isn't a single `else` statement in your code

Comment: If you want to discount something then you should calculate the discount and subtract it from the full price. You are assigning the discount to the variable that contains the full price

Comment: Regarding If..else statements, here `<65` and `>=65` can be considered as base condition so you can put this condition in if..else block and remaining code can be reused as the conditions are same, you can put it into function

Comment: It is probably better to structure the code according to your input being radio buttons, using `else` blocks to handle this. Additionally I would declare variables to hold the percentage along with the bonus (from age >= 65), and then only do the actual discount calculation once, at the bottom, using the if-statements to set the variables to the right percent and bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your conditions for age >= 65 and calculate the discount for these conditions and in the else part calculate the discount for the condition age < 65

Also when you calculate a discount you use a separate variable and subtract that variable from the total amount.

```
public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime todate = DateTime.Today;
    int CurrentYear = todate.Year;
    int price = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Price.Text);
    int ammount = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Ammount.Text);
    int dob = Convert.ToInt32(tb_dob.Text);
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear - dob);
    double result = Convert.ToDouble(price * ammount);
    double discount = 0d;

    if (age >= 65)
    {
        if (rbkorting5.IsChecked)
            discount = result * 0.05 + 10;
        else if (rbkorting10.IsChecked)
            discount = result * 0.10 + 10;
        else if (rbkorting15.IsChecked)
            discount = result * 0.15 + 10;
    }
    else
    {
        if (rbkorting5.IsChecked))
            discount = result * 0.05;
        else if (rbkorting10.IsChecked)
            discount = result * 0.10;
        else if (rbkorting15.IsChecked)
            discount = result * 0.15;
    }

    lb_result.Content = result - discount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime todate = DateTime.Today;
    int CurrentYear = todate.Year;
    int price = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Price.Text);
    int ammount = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Ammount.Text);
    int dob = Convert.ToInt32(tb_dob.Text);
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear - dob);
    double result = Convert.ToDouble(price * ammount);

    lb_result.Content = SubstractDiscount(result);
}

private double SubstractDiscount(double amount)
{
    double discount = 1;
    double additionalAgeDiscount = 0;

    if(rbkorting5.IsChecked)
       discount = 0.05;
    if(rbkorting10.IsChecked)
       discount = 0.10;
    if(rbkorting15.IsChecked)
       discount = 0.15;

    if(age >= 65)
       additionalAgeDiscount = 10;

   return amount * discount + additionalAgeDiscount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could organize your code as below based on discount and age:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DateTime todate = DateTime.Today;
        int CurrentYear = todate.Year;
        int price = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Price.Text);
        int ammount = Convert.ToInt32(tb_Ammount.Text);
        double result = Convert.ToDouble(price * ammount);
        int dob = Convert.ToInt32(tb_dob.Text);
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear - dob);
        if (rbkorting5.Checked == true)  {
            if (age >= 65) result = result * 0.05 + 10;
            else result = result * 0.05; 
        }
        else if(rbkorting10.Checked == true) {
            if (age >= 65) result = result * 0.1 + 10;
            else result = result * 0.1;
        }
        else if(rbkorting15.Checked == true) {
            if (age >= 65) result = result * 0.15 + 10;
            else result = result * 0.15;
        }
        lb_result.Content = result;  //==> return discount result
    }
```